# What version of dash is needed for core components to work?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I made the mistake of updating a package near the end of a project that utilized the dash core components (to get a feature to work). The project has stopped working. According to this site it states it is dependent on dash, but fails to work with the latest version of dash if I understand correctly. Is there an easy way to get these packages to work again?

https://pypi.org/project/dash-core-components/2.0.0/

**Packages I was using:**

```
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
```

**Error I get now:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-8a1bdb142803> in <module>
      1 import wikipedia
      2 import dash
----> 3 import dash_core_components as dcc
      4 #import dash_html_components as html
      5 from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dash_core_components\__init__.py in <module>
----> 1 from dash.dcc import *  # noqa: F401, F403, E402
      2 from dash.dcc import __version__  # noqa: F401, F403, E402
      3 import warnings
      4 
      5 warnings.warn(

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dash.dcc'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to go back to be able to use dash core components. They are still part of dash, they have just moved to the main repo.
By installing dash `pip install dash` you are already installing dash_core_components. But, you will need to access the library like this:

```
from dash import dcc
```

instead of how it was before

```
import dash_core_components as dcc
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Still getting error: cannot import name 'dcc' from 'dash'.

Comment: Very weird. I installed the last version of dash on a new virtual env and the import worked. Can you look at which dash version you have? Mine is 2.0.0. What can maybe be happening is that your env still has the dash-core-components from the versions before.  I guess something you could do is uninstall dash on your virtualenv and install again to get the last version from scratch.

Comment: Uninstalling it and reinstalling it worked. Got a bunch of odd warnings, but it is working!