# Plotly Dash ImportError: cannot import name 'dcc' from 'dash'

Tags: python, import, plotly, plotly-dash, dashboard

I'm just trying to get the Dash tutorial up and running but every time I try to run it, copy and pasted from the documentation into my asdf.py I get the error "ImportError: cannot import name 'dcc' from 'dash'". I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling dash, along with renaming the file and got nowhere. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

```
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output

app = Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H6("Change the value in the text box to see callbacks in action!"),
    html.Div([
        "Input: ",
        dcc.Input(id='my-input', value='initial value', type='text')
    ]),
    html.Br(),
    html.Div(id='my-output'),

])
```

Comment: Sounds like a version issue. What version of dash do you have installed? Also, have you seen [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70705454/what-version-of-dash-is-needed-for-core-components-to-work)?

Comment: Hmm. I was originally trying with 1.4.1 so I tried 1.14.0 and 1.19.0 and got the same error on all of them. Strangely enough, when I tried running the same program from a Jupyter cell, it did not get the import error, and instead got "zmq.error.ZMQError: Address already in use" which I constantly get, regardless of the port I set to use.

Comment: If you're using dash 1.x then you need to import dcc (and html) separately:
`import dash_core_components as dcc` and `import dash_html_components as html`. The current version of dash is 2.2.0. 
[dcc](https://pypi.org/project/dash-core-components/) (and [html](https://pypi.org/project/dash-html-components/)) are in the main dash repo as of dash 2 (Python >=3.6)

Comment: I am facing the same issue. the import actually works when calling it in the python console, but I have the same error when trying to import it from a Jupyter Notebook. Did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 8):

Either try:
`pip install dash --upgrade`

or instead (for older versions):
`import dash_core_components as dcc`
`import dash_html_components as html`
`from dash.dependencies import Input, Output`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this is the only thread for this specific problem. I ran the same code on Jupyter Notebooks only and never got an error. However when I opened the same notebook in VSCode it gave me the error. It also gave me an error for Flask. I resolved the error by downgrading my Python version to Python 3.9 - and magically I had no more import errors. My codeblock below for my imports. Uncomment the from dash-depencies and test:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px  # (version 4.7.0 or higher)
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import dash_core_components as dcc
#from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output
```